# Jenkinsfile script to waitUntil a folder is created

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile, groovy

With this Jenkinsfile code, I am trying to test A/B folder creation, and also testing if waitUntil works till the folder is created, I expect it to wait for 0 secs as the folder is created before `waitUntil` gets called.

```
stage('other job') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            timeout(10) {
                                def folder = new File( 'A/B' )
                                println "Waiting for " + folder
                                println "fe==" + folder.exists()
                                waitUntil {
                                    if(folder.exists()) {
                                        return(true)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

It fails with below error, what's wrong here? the folder is not gerrit created in workspace.

```
Timeout set to expire in 10 min
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] echo
Waiting for A/B
[Pipeline] echo
fe==false
[Pipeline] waitUntil
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // waitUntil
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
...
Failed in branch other job
...
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.ClassCastException: body return value null is not boolean
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.WaitForConditionStep$Callback.onSuccess(WaitForConditionStep.java:167)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution$SuccessAdapter.receive(CpsBodyExecution.java:377)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your block expression doesn't return a value in all cases.

Try this instead:

```
waitUntil { folder.exists() }
```

Comment: Same, I changed timeout to 10, and pointed `folder` to a known existing dir, it keeps waiting for 10 mins and timesout.

Comment: I worked it around with `waitUntil {  def r = sh script: "[[ -d 'A/B' ]]", returnStatus: true
                                        return r == 0}`

Comment: Beware of using java or groovy File exists method and prefer [fileExists](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#fileexists-verify-if-file-exists-in-workspace) or shell.  Pipeline steps figure out that they should work on the agent.  The File methods may execute on controller where file is not.  CPS can be a challenge